# Self join through junction table?

Tags: sql

I have a list of users, and a junction table where both fields are `user_id`, which represents a friendship.

So the database is

## users

```
id    |    name
----------------------
1        Julia
2        Davos
3        Michael
4        Anthony
```

## friendships

```
user1_id    |    user2_id
--------------------------
3                    1
2                    4
```

I want to select a list of the friendships, like

```
Michael    |    Julia
Davos      |    Anthony
```

But this one is just totally stumping me, and Google isn't helping. Can anyone offer a tip?

Comment: Start with the `friendships` table, joining to `users` twice. For each use of `users`, use a different alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For get that information you should join twice to user table using friendship like pivot

```
   SELECT friend_1.name,friend_2.name
   FROM friendships AS relation_friend
   JOIN users AS friend_1 ON friend_1.id=relation_friend.user1_id
   JOIN users AS friend_2 ON friend_1.id=relation_friend.user1_id;
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

It is dynamically working fine for any number of data:

```
select tbl.name, tb2.name from
(select *
 from 
users as a
inner join
friendships as b
on a.id=b.user1_id
or a.id=b.user2_id) as tbl
inner join
(select *
 from 
users as a
inner join
friendships as b
on a.id=b.user1_id
or a.id=b.user2_id) as tb2
on tbl.user2_id=tb2.id
where tbl.name <> tb2.name
```

Comment: @jorge-polanco Your query returning 8 rows but it need to return only 4. I can't able to fetch the exact result from your query.